# Web App en producción no se conecta con Google People Api. No funciona con IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, iis, google-api

En mi trabajo utilizo una web app (asp.net core 2.2) para hacer seguimientos de expedientes, etc. Se crea un usuario y luego cada uno que lo usa se "loguea" para ingresar a la aplicación.

Se me ocurrió de hacer una llamada a la API de Google People para usar el avatar de la cuenta de Google. En modo de desarrollo funciona de maravillas, me redirige efectivamente a la página de consentimiento, grabo el token de acceso para después hacer la llamada y grabar la respuesta de la url del avatar, etc. La llamada a la API de Google se hace luego que el usuario se loguea. En resumen funciona.

El problema aparece cuando la App está en producción.

Digo que hay un problema porque luego de hacer el login, el explorador se queda pensando, no avanza y no muestra la pantalla de ingreso a la web app, ni siquiera la pantalla de consentimiento de OAuth2.0. Si saco la llamada a la API, la app funciona bien, pero no tengo ningún avatar.

La app corre bajo IIS y están dados los permisos en la carpeta para lectura y escritura.

```
UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream =
            new FileStream(credencialPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { "profile", PeopleService.Scope.ContactsReadonly },
                usuario,
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(tokenPath, true));

        }


        var service = new PeopleService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "App",

        });

        string url = "https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=photos";

        string accessToken = credential.Token.AccessToken;
        service.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        var resultado = await service.HttpClient.GetAsync(url);
        var contenido = resultado.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        dynamic datos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(contenido.Result);

        if (urlAvatar == null)
        {
            //hago lo necesario para grabar la respuesta.
        }
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Lo he dejado por mas de 10 minutos corriendo y no me larga ningún tipo de error, ni el log ni nada. Por eso no se que mas hacer.

**Actualización 18/03/2020**

La app corre bajo IIS.
Cuando ejecuto la App mediante el comando `dotnet [nombreapp].dll` desde la carpeta *inetpub* funciona perfecto. Se abre una nueva pestaña con la pantalla de consentimiento para dar permiso de lectura del avatar y se generan los token necesarios.

Ahora bien, cuando lo ejecuto a través de IIS no logro hacer que funcione.

Lo que más me pone en duda de porque no funciona es que ya tengo otra llamada a Google Calendar API y me funciona, aún corriendo desde IIS.

Lo que tiene este nuevo código para Google People API es que quiero que genere un token diferente para cada usuario que se loguea.

**Actualización 18/03/2020 n°2**

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }


        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {


            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<JudicialDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppJudicial")));

            services.AddDbContext<GestionDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppGestion")));

            services.AddDbContext<SecretariaDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppSecretaria")));

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangFire")));
            services.AddHangfireServer();

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .UseSerilogLogProvider();

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(config =>
            {
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                // Password settings
                config.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                config.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                config.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                config.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                config.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 2;
                config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            })
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddErrorDescriber<SpanishIdentityErrorDescriber>();


            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ConsentCookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);
            });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);


            services.AddScoped<IRegistroService, RegistroService>();

            services.AddScoped<IGoogleService, GoogleService>();

            services.AddTransient<ISaldosService, SaldosService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

            services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);
            services.Configure<GoogleApiOptions>(Configuration);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {

            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {

                new CultureInfo("es-AR")
            };
            app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "es-AR", uiCulture: "es-AR"),
                SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
            });

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }          

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
            {
                Authorization = new[] { new MyAuthorizationFilter() }
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "areas",
                  template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            RotativaConfiguration.Setup(env);
        }

        public class MyAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
        {
            public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
            {
                var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();

                return httpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin");
            }
        }


    }
```

**Program.cs**

```
 public class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()                
                .Enrich.WithMachineName()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .CreateLogger();
            try
            {
                Log.Information("La aplicación se inició correctamente");
                CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
                    .Build()
                    .Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               Log.Fatal(ex, "La aplicación no pudo iniciar correctamente");
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }

        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .UseStartup<Startup>();

    }
```

En la imagen que coloco, al parámetro maracado en rojo cuando lo cambio por ejemplo a `"user"` funciona bien. Evidentemente el problema está ahí, pero el inconveniente es que el avatar que me "trae" de Google People es del primero que se loguea. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Ese `usuario` que se ve en la imagen corresponde al usuario que actualmente se loguea a la web app

[link con problema similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064047/google-auth-runs-in-visual-studio-but-hangs-when-deployed-to-iis)

Alguna idea?
Gracias por leer.
Saludos.

Comment: Publica lo que tienes en tu startup.cs me late que hay algún orden diferente para producción. también publica tu program.cs

Comment: @fredyfx ahi edite y agregue lo que me pediste. Saludos.

Comment: En el startup: .UseSerilog().UseIISIntegration()

Comment: @fredyfx ahí implementé lo que me aconsejaste, pero sigue el mismo resultado. No se abre la ventana para el consentimiento de Google. Lo que leí en internet y en stackoverflow (inglés) es que la implementación de la librería tal cual la estoy usando para la autorización no es complatible con IIS, pero me surje la duda porque como dije antes, si cambio ese parámetro me funciona perfecto.

Comment: Me llama la atención que no sea compatible con IIS. ¿Podrías editar la pregunta y agregar los enlaces de tu investigación por favor?

Comment: @fredyfx ahí agregué un link. Mañana sigo buscando y los agrego.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pude hacerlo funcionar de la siguiente manera:

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow;

            flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer()
            {
                ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets()
                {
                    ClientId = Options.ClientId,
                    ClientSecret = Options.ClientSecret
                },
                Scopes = scope,
                DataStore = new FileDataStore(archivoToken)

            });

            if(code == null)
            {
                var auth = $"{flow.AuthorizationServerUrl}?client_id={Options.ClientId}&redirect_uri={uri}&response_type=code&scope={scope.FirstOrDefault()}&access_type=offline&prompt=consent";

                Response.Redirect(auth);
            }
            if (code != null)
            {

                TokenResponse tokenResponse = new TokenResponse();
                tokenResponse = await flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync(
                  user.Email, 
                  code,
                  uri,
                  CancellationToken.None);                

                UserCredential userCredential = new UserCredential(flow, user.Email, tokenResponse);

                //CREO EL SERVICIO
                var service = new PeopleService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = userCredential,
                    ApplicationName = "AppCarola"
                });
              }
```

Actualmente corre bien bajo IIS y la pantalla de consentimiento se abré como cuando funciona bajo VS.

Hay un paquete de NuGet que es compatible con asp.net core [aquí está](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/tree/master/Src/Support)

Lo estuve probando y funciona perfecto. Pero en mi caso por cuestión de preferencia decidí usar el cógido que subo.

Saludos!!